# Need for IQueryable ToArray AND ToList chained

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a Pluralsight course where the author is explaining that in order to return a proper collection (and not a Lazily loaded one as the result from an entity framework query), it's needed to do a ToArray operation. So far so good, but then he explains that on an `IQueryable` you can't do `ToArray()`, so he needs to actually do `query.ToList().ToArray();`

Is it true you actually need both methods? I've modified the code and seems to work with `ToList()` just the same as with `ToArray()` (the method is expected to return an `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: If the caller expects an `IEnumerable<T>` to be returned then doing the `ToList()` is sufficient, you do not need to call `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems ... off. [MSDN's Documentation on IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb351562(v=vs.100).aspx) has both `ToList()` and `ToArray()` as valid extension methods.`

Using both `ToList()` and `ToArray()` seems overly redundant and potentially non-performant on big collections (Don't quote me on this, purely speculation! :) )

`T[]` and `List<T>` both implement `IEnumerable<T>` so as long as the method returns `IEnumerable<T>` then it shouldn't matter.

```
 public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
 {
  return Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                   .ToList();
 }

 public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
 {
  return Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                   .ToArray();
 }

 public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
 {
  return Enumerable.Range(0,10);
 }
```

All of these aforementioned methods, will compile and build correctly. Assuming there not in the same class, but that's a different problem.

Now, these following methods won't:

```
 public List<int> GetNumbers()
 {
  // Compile error as int[] and List<int> are different types
  return Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                   .ToArray(); 
 }

 public int[] GetNumbers()
 {
  // Compile error as int[] and List<int> are different types
  return Enumerable.Range(0,10)
                   .ToList(); 
 }
```

Comment: Right. I was asking just in case the community was aware of any obscure reason why one would want to do that :)